# Crashes everytime I open the app

Tags: bug, ios-app, iphone

After I receivd a notification that someone answer my question, opened app from the notification and app crashed. Unfortunately, it crashes every time I try to open. The app is totally unusable now. Please fix.

iphone 6, os 9.1